# PHP merge two arrays on the same key AND value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. And I want to merge them on the same key AND value. If they have the same `ur_user_id` then they are merged. `array2` only provides some additional data for `array1`, so the `new_array.length` = `array1.length`. `array1` just gets the additional data from `array2`.

```
$array1 =    
    array(
        array('ur_user_id'=> 1,'ur_fname'=>'PerA','ur_lname'=>'SonA'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 2,'ur_fname'=>'PerB','ur_lname'=>'SonB'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 3,'ur_fname'=>'PerC','ur_lname'=>'SonC'),
    );
$array2 = 
    array(
        array('ur_user_id' => 5,'ur_code' => 'EE','ur_user_role' => 'testE'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 4,'ur_code' => 'DD','ur_user_role' => 'testD'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 6,'ur_code' => 'FF','ur_user_role' => 'testF'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 3,'ur_code' => 'CC','ur_user_role' => 'testC'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 1,'ur_code' => 'AA','ur_user_role' => 'testA'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 2,'ur_code' => 'BB','ur_user_role' => 'testB'),
    );
```

Then the new array must look like this. It will have both the values from the `array1` and `array2`.

```
$new_array =    
    array(
        array('ur_user_id'=> 1,'ur_fname'=>'PerA','ur_lname'=>'SonA','ur_code' => 'AA','ur_user_role' => 'testA'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 2,'ur_fname'=>'PerB','ur_lname'=>'SonB','ur_code' => 'BB','ur_user_role' => 'testB'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 3,'ur_fname'=>'PerC','ur_lname'=>'SonC','ur_code' => 'CC','ur_user_role' => 'testC'),
    );
```

The `array1.length` is always less than or equal to `array2.length` never greater. And the order of both arrays will not be always ordered. I've tried the function below which I got somewhere here but it doesn't work for me and I'm not really good with loops.

```
function merge_common_keys(){
    $arr = func_get_args();
    $num = func_num_args();

    $keys = array();
    $i = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<$num; ++$i){
        $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($arr[$i]));
    }
    $keys = array_unique($keys);

    $merged = array();

    foreach ($keys as $key){
        $merged[$key] = array();
        for($i=0; $i<$num; ++$i){
            $merged[$key][] = isset($arr[$i][$key]) ? $arr[$i][$key] : null;
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

Based on the given arrays the result is like this. It only merges on the same key.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ur_user_id] => 1
                    [ur_fname] => PerA
                    [ur_lname] => SonA
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ur_user_id] => 5
                    [ur_code] => AA-BB-CC
                    [ur_user_role] => testE
                )

        )
```

Comment: @NareshKumar that's on the same key, not the value inside the key.

Comment: @iamdevlinph I cannot sensibly use this page to close newer pages because there are so many flawed and indirect answers here (ergo, researchers will waste a lot of time reading answers that should not be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code, It might help you, it's short and without traversing loops:

```
    usort($array2,function($a,$b){
        return strnatcmp($a['ur_user_id'],$b['ur_user_id']);
    });
    $array3 = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);

    $result = array_uintersect($array3,$array1,function($a,$b){
        return strnatcmp($a['ur_user_id'],$b['ur_user_id']);
    });
    print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ur_user_id] => 1
            [ur_fname] => PerA
            [ur_lname] => SonA
            [ur_code] => AA
            [ur_user_role] => testA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ur_user_id] => 2
            [ur_fname] => PerB
            [ur_lname] => SonB
            [ur_code] => BB
            [ur_user_role] => testB
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ur_user_id] => 3
            [ur_fname] => PerC
            [ur_lname] => SonC
            [ur_code] => CC
            [ur_user_role] => testC
        )

)
```

And Here is [Demo](https://3v4l.org/mhvL9)

Comment: Avoiding loops is not necessarily an advantage.  I find sorting to be an unnecessary step for this task. Your answer will break when the first 3 subarrays for array1 are not the first 3 subarrays of array2.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/7unT8 `array_replace_recursive()` is not a very direct approach for this task and it is not properly implemented.

Comment: This solution is limited to 2 arrays.
I tried to put it in a loop but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to make iterated checks/searches for values (effectively a unique identifier), the best performing approach will often:

1. generate a keyed array and
2. make iterated calls of `isset()` (instead of `in_array()` or `array_search()`)

`ur_user_id` is your "unique identifier".
`$array2` is prepared by assigning `ur_user_id` values as keys with `array_column()`.
`$array1` controls the number of iterations.
My approach will check for a corresponding row between `$array1` and `$array2` (to avoid *Notices*) before using a union operator (`+=`) to append the `$array2` data to each original row of `$array1`.
The `&` in the foreach loop "modifies by reference" -- this means the *actual* input array is being "dealt with" instead of a *copy* of the input array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8hl1u))

```
$array1 =    
    array(
        array('ur_user_id'=> 1,'ur_fname'=>'PerA','ur_lname'=>'SonA'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 2,'ur_fname'=>'PerB','ur_lname'=>'SonB'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 3,'ur_fname'=>'PerC','ur_lname'=>'SonC'),
    );
$array2 = 
    array(
        array('ur_user_id' => 5,'ur_code' => 'EE','ur_user_role' => 'testE'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 4,'ur_code' => 'DD','ur_user_role' => 'testD'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 6,'ur_code' => 'FF','ur_user_role' => 'testF'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 3,'ur_code' => 'CC','ur_user_role' => 'testC'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 1,'ur_code' => 'AA','ur_user_role' => 'testA'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 2,'ur_code' => 'BB','ur_user_role' => 'testB'),
    );  

$keyed = array_column($array2, NULL, 'ur_user_id'); // replace indexes with ur_user_id values

foreach ($array1 as &$row) {       // write directly to $array1 while iterating
    if (isset($keyed[$row['ur_user_id']])) { // check if shared key exists
        $row += $keyed[$row['ur_user_id']]; // append associative elements
    }
}

var_export($array1);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ur_user_id' => 1,
    'ur_fname' => 'PerA',
    'ur_lname' => 'SonA',
    'ur_code' => 'AA',
    'ur_user_role' => 'testA',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ur_user_id' => 2,
    'ur_fname' => 'PerB',
    'ur_lname' => 'SonB',
    'ur_code' => 'BB',
    'ur_user_role' => 'testB',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ur_user_id' => 3,
    'ur_fname' => 'PerC',
    'ur_lname' => 'SonC',
    'ur_code' => 'CC',
    'ur_user_role' => 'testC',
  ),
)
```

Comment: This for me worked like a charm.
Now the problem I am facing is that if there doesn't exists a key and for the same I want to add a blank key & value pair. How can it be done.?

Comment: @golchha21 When you ask your new question, create some sample arrays that setup the issue?  Show your coding attempt. Then show the exact output that you desire.

Comment: @golchha21 Do you mean something like this?  https://3v4l.org/ojJZ9  It is too hard to guess your desired behavior/output without a complete question write up.

Comment: Hey @mickmackusa Thanks for asking but was able to get the desired result by looping the arrays with the master array that I generated.

Comment: This question ain't mine. So I cannot accept or reject the answer.
Also the answer you provided was up voted by me and the accepted answer was down voted.

Comment: Oh yeah.  Sorry, didn't take notice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$array1 =    
    array(
        array('ur_user_id'=> 1,'ur_fname'=>'PerA','ur_lname'=>'SonA'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 2,'ur_fname'=>'PerB','ur_lname'=>'SonB'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 3,'ur_fname'=>'PerC','ur_lname'=>'SonC'),
    );
$array2 = 
    array(
        array('ur_user_id' => 5,'ur_code' => 'EE','ur_user_role' => 'testE'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 4,'ur_code' => 'DD','ur_user_role' => 'testD'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 6,'ur_code' => 'FF','ur_user_role' => 'testF'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 3,'ur_code' => 'CC','ur_user_role' => 'testC'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 1,'ur_code' => 'AA','ur_user_role' => 'testA'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 2,'ur_code' => 'BB','ur_user_role' => 'testB'),
    );


$result = array();

$userIdsFromArray1 = array_column($array1, 'ur_user_id');


foreach($array2 as $subarray)
{
    if(in_array($subarray['ur_user_id'], $userIdsFromArray1))
    {
        $result[] = array_merge($subarray, getDataFromArray1ByUserId($array1, $subarray['ur_user_id']));
    }
}


function getDataFromArray1ByUserId($array1, $userId)
{
    foreach($array1 as $key => $data)
    {
        if($data['ur_user_id'] == $userId)
            return $data;
    }

    return array();
}

 usort($result,function($a,$b){
    return strnatcmp($a['ur_user_id'],$b['ur_user_id']);
});

print_r($result);
```

**Working example : [CLICK!](https://eval.in/574242)**

Comment: "_Try this_" (code only) answers are low value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and future researchers.  Every time you post an answer, please include some explanation to make your solution (and this site) more valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this three line code in foreach loop like this :

```
$array1 =    
    array(
        array('ur_user_id'=> 1,'ur_fname'=>'PerA','ur_lname'=>'SonA'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 2,'ur_fname'=>'PerB','ur_lname'=>'SonB'),
        array('ur_user_id'=> 3,'ur_fname'=>'PerC','ur_lname'=>'SonC'),
    );
$array2 = 
    array(
        array('ur_user_id' => 5,'ur_code' => 'EE','ur_user_role' => 'testE'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 4,'ur_code' => 'DD','ur_user_role' => 'testD'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 6,'ur_code' => 'FF','ur_user_role' => 'testF'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 3,'ur_code' => 'CC','ur_user_role' => 'testC'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 1,'ur_code' => 'AA','ur_user_role' => 'testA'),
        array('ur_user_id' => 2,'ur_code' => 'BB','ur_user_role' => 'testB'),
    );

$newArray =array(); 

foreach($array1 as $key => $val)
{
    $ids = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['ur_user_id'];}, $array2); //get the all the user ids from array 2
    $k = array_search($val['ur_user_id'],$ids); // find the key of user id in ids array
    $newArray[] = array_merge($array1[$key],$array2[$k]); /// merge the first array key with second
}   

echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArray);
```

This will give you :

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ur_user_id] => 1
            [ur_fname] => PerA
            [ur_lname] => SonA
            [ur_code] => AA
            [ur_user_role] => testA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ur_user_id] => 2
            [ur_fname] => PerB
            [ur_lname] => SonB
            [ur_code] => BB
            [ur_user_role] => testB
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ur_user_id] => 3
            [ur_fname] => PerC
            [ur_lname] => SonC
            [ur_code] => CC
            [ur_user_role] => testC
        )

)
```

***[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/574256)***

Comment: You should not be re-mapping `$ids` on each iteration of the `foreach()`. This solution is not refined/efficient.  Why use `$array1[$key]` when `$val` will do?

Answer (score -1):

You better go with this:

[Working Example](https://3v4l.org/Ucs7r)

```
$ids = array();
$out = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if(isset($array2[$key]))
        $out[$key][] = $array2[$key];
    $out[$key][] = $value;
    $ids[] = $array2[$key]['ur_user_id'];
}

foreach($array2 as $key => $val){
    if(!in_array($val['ur_user_id'], $ids))
        $out[$key][] = $array2[$key];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have both the values from `array1` and `array2`. After merging it must look like this: `array('ur_user_id'=> 1,'ur_fname'=>'PerA','ur_lname'=>'SonA','ur_code' => 'AA','ur_user_role' => 'testA')`

Comment: So you need to match the index??? So what about the rest of the element of `array2`???

Comment: The `array2` provides some additional info for `array1`. So the basis of this is only the `array1`.

Comment: Every answer on Stackoverflow should include an explanation.  Don't assume to know the knowledge level of every future research who will visit this page.  This site is an educational resource ...not just to the OP but to other readers as well.  There is never a good reason for a code-only answer.