# PHP Match by common key of two multidimentional array and merge the two array with both array key

Tags: php

Good evening, I have a little bit problem. I have two array. like

```
$firstArr = Array(
                [0] => Array(                   
                    [customer_id] => 11,
                    [home_delivery] => no,
            ),
                [1] => Array(
                    [customer_id] => 12,
                    [home_delivery] => no,
            ),
                [2] => Array(
                    [customer_id] => 13,
                    [home_delivery] => no,
            ),
        );

        $secondArr = Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [customer_id] => 11,
                    [test] => no,
                    [is_active] => yes,
            ),
                [1] => Array(
                    [customer_id] => 22,
                    [test] => no,
                    [is_active] => yes,
            ),
        );
```

Now i want to get the result like first array's customer_id match with the second array customer_id. Id two array's customer id is same the the value of second array add with first array otherwise the value will be null. Hope guys you got my point what i want. The output which i want is like the below.

```
$getResult = Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [customer_id] => 11,
                    [home_delivery] => no,
                    [test] => no,
                    [is_active] => yes,
            ),
                [1] => Array(
                    [customer_id] => 12,
                    [home_delivery] => no,
                    [test] => '',
                    [is_active] => '',
            ),
                [2] => Array(
                    [customer_id] => 13,
                    [home_delivery] => no,
                    [test] => '',
                    [is_active] => '',
            ),
        );
```

I have tried by this code, but it doesnt work. Please help me.

```
$mergedArray = array();
        foreach ($firstArr as $index1 => $value1) {
            foreach ($secondArr as $index2 => $value2) {
                if ($array1[$index1]['customer_id'] == $array2[$index2]['customer_id']) {
                    $mergedArray[] = array_merge($firstArr[$index1], $secondArr[$index2]);
                }
            }
        }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($mergedArray); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: You can read this post where talk about almost your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342992/php-merge-two-arrays-on-the-same-key-and-value

Comment: Did you omit id=22 from the result array by accident, or do you only want items from the second array that are in the first array.

Comment: If these arrays happen to come from your database you'd be better off using a join instead of two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
<?php 

        $results = [];
        // Get all unique keys from both arrays
        $keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($firstArr[0]), array_keys($secondArr[0])));

        // Make array of common customer_ids
        foreach (array_merge($firstArr, $secondArr) as $record) {
            $results[$record['customer_id']] = isset($results[$record['customer_id']]) ? array_merge($results[$record['customer_id']], $record) : $record;
        }
        // Fill keys which are not present with blank strings
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            foreach ($results as $index => $result) {
                if(!array_key_exists($key, $result)){
                    $results[$index][$key] = '';
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$firstArr = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'customer_id' => 11,
        'home_delivery' => 'no'
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'customer_id' => 12,
        'home_delivery' => 'no'
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'customer_id' => 13,
        'home_delivery' => 'no'
    )
);

$secondArr = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'customer_id' => 11,
        'test' => 'no',
        'is_active' => 'yes'
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'customer_id' => 22,
        'test' => 'no',
        'is_active' => 'yes'
    )
);

$secondKey = array_column($secondArr,'customer_id');

foreach($firstArr as &$value){
    $idx2 = array_search($value['customer_id'], $secondKey);

    $value = array_merge($value, [
        'test' => false !== $idx2 ? $secondArr[$idx2]['test'] : '',
        'is_active' => false !== $idx2 ? $secondArr[$idx2]['is_active'] : '',
    ]);
}
print_r($firstArr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customer_id] => 11
            [home_delivery] => no
            [test] => no
            [is_active] => yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [customer_id] => 12
            [home_delivery] => no
            [test] => 
            [is_active] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [customer_id] => 13
            [home_delivery] => no
            [test] => 
            [is_active] => 
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2356db9b6cb55bfbb3b67f6836a3cdf6cf93dc1)

There are 2 "tricks" I use here, the first, and more important one, is `array_column` this picks just one column from an array, but the thing is the keys in the resulting array will match the original array.  Which we can take advantage of.

The array we get from array column looks like this:

```
array (
   0 => 11,
   1 => 22
);
```

Because the keys match the original array we can use `array_search` (with the ID) to look up that key, which we can then use in the original array. This gives us an "easier" way to search the second array by flattening it out.

So for example when we look up `$firstArr['customer_id'] = 11` in the above array we get the key `0` (which is not boolean false, see below). Then we can take that index and use it for the original array `$secondArr` and get the values from the other 2 columns.

-Note- that array search returns boolean false when it cant find the item, because PHP treats 0 and false the same we have to do a strict type check `!==` instead of just `!=`.  Otherwise PHP will confuse the 0 index with being false, which is not something we want.

The second "trick" is use `&` in the foreach value, this is by reference which allows us to modify the array used in the loop, directly. This is optional as you could just as easily create a new array instead. But I thought I would show it as an option.

Comment: thankz a lot..Its working..sorry for late reply..:)